# problemas ao criar timer no EJB

Tags: java, ejb

Boa noite galera,

Estou com problema na criação de um timer, não tenho experiencias anteriores com aplicações que sejam executadas dessa forma.

o erro acontece na classe CargaDados.

segue o codigo do timer:

```
 @Schedule(minute="*/2", second="0", dayOfMonth="*", month="*", year="*", hour="6-23", dayOfWeek="*", persistent = false)
public void cargaC() {
....}



@Schedule(minute="10", second="0", dayOfMonth="*", month="*", year="*", hour="1", dayOfWeek="*", persistent = false)
    public void limpaTabelaC(){
    ....}
```

erro ocorrido:

```
18:56:10,103 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (EJB default - 4) JBAS014121: Timer: [id=c7a5c2c9-2b6c-49d8-956a-f831ebab53c3 timedObjectId=PrjX_V2.PrjX_V2.CargaDados auto-timer?:true persistent?:false timerService=org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.TimerServiceImpl@35d07654 initialExpiration=Wed May 11 06:00:00 BRT 2016 intervalDuration(in milli sec)=0 nextExpiration=Wed May 11 18:58:00 BRT 2016 timerState=IN_TIMEOUT will be retried
18:56:10,103 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (EJB default - 4) JBAS014123: Retrying timeout for timer: [id=c7a5c2c9-2b6c-49d8-956a-f831ebab53c3 timedObjectId=PrjX_V2.PrjX_V2.CargaDados auto-timer?:true persistent?:false timerService=org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.TimerServiceImpl@35d07654 initialExpiration=Wed May 11 06:00:00 BRT 2016 intervalDuration(in milli sec)=0 nextExpiration=Wed May 11 18:58:00 BRT 2016 timerState=IN_TIMEOUT
18:56:14,813 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (EJB default - 4) JBAS014122: Error during retrying timeout for timer: [id=c7a5c2c9-2b6c-49d8-956a-f831ebab53c3 timedObjectId=PrjX_V2.PrjX_V2.CargaDados auto-timer?:true persistent?:false timerService=org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.TimerServiceImpl@35d07654 initialExpiration=Wed May 11 06:00:00 BRT 2016 intervalDuration(in milli sec)=0 nextExpiration=Wed May 11 18:58:00 BRT 2016 timerState=RETRY_TIMEOUT: javax.ejb.EJBException: Unexpected Error
```

alguem sabe me ajudar?